# Best way to structure Core Data fetch for items, based on attribute(s) at other end of to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I am building a self-quiz style app. It is basically a collection view of full-screen slides. Each slide has multiple annotations that the user taps to test themselves. The slides are grouped into categories, the user can filter by category.

I would like to implement the ability to also filter the annotations based on whether the user has marked them known/not known/etc. My current data model (relevant parts) looks like this:

```
---------------        ---------------------------------------------
| Slide       |        | Annotation                                |
---------------        ---------------------------------------------
| name        |        | lastKnown (enum for known/not known/etc.) |
| category    |        | ...                                       |
---------------        ---------------------------------------------
| annotations | <--->> | slide                                     |        
---------------        ---------------------------------------------
```

Since the last known/not known/etc. response lives in the annotation object, it seems to me that I need to:

1. Create a fetch (for my NSFetchedResultsController) on the slide entity
2. Use a predicate for the selected categories (so I only get slides from that category)
3. Filter on whether the slide has any annotations where the lastKnown matches the selected known/not known/etc filter (so that if a slide from that category does not have any annotations that match the selected known/not known/etc. filter, it is excluded)

I'm all set on 1 and 2, but having trouble on 3. My understanding at this point is that each slide's annotation relationship will return an NSSet of the annotation objects. It seems I need to test each of these to see if they match the criteria in the known/not known/etc. filter. It also seems to me that I should do it in a predicate, so I can just reload the collection view to refresh the data.

Can anyone offer some best practices on the most efficient way to approach 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [ANY](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) operation:

```
NSPredicate *slidePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == 'category'"];

NSPredicate *annotationPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY annotations.lastKnown = 'known'"];

NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[slidePredicate, annotationPredicate]];
```